# trying to redirect to an error page if extension is written in REQUEST_URI

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

imagine this condition:

i have a website and i want to remove extensions, and i want to redirect user to an error page if there is any extension (.php, .asp, .html , etc) in the REQUEST_URI variable,
i've done like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{3,8})/?$ $1.php [L]
```

so when i try to open `example.com/blog/`, it adds the extension to the requested SCRIPT_NAME, but REQUEST_URI doesn't have a .php extension according to server side variable $_SERVER,

> 'REQUEST_URI' => string '/blog' (length=5)
>
> 'SCRIPT_NAME' => string '/blog.php' (length=9)

but when i try to open example.com/blog.php, the .php extension is inside REQUEST_URI,

> 'REQUEST_URI' => string '/blog.php' (length=9)
>
> 'SCRIPT_NAME' => string '/blog.php' (length=9)

and i want to use a RewriteCond to check and see if this is true (by checking if there is a dot '.' or anything following that inside it), and if this is true, i want to redirect user to an error page, i've done like below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \\.[a-zA-Z_-]*/?

RewriteRule ".*" example.com/err [R]
```

but after adding these two lines to my htaccess, whether or not i write the extension inside url, it redirects me to the error page.
apparently REQUEST_URI does contain extension both times although the server says differently.
this is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "\\.[a-zA-Z_-]*/?$"

RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z_-]*) localhost/example/err [R]
```

any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: check the htaccess of symfony2 this will help you much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i could achieve my goal using THE_REQUEST variable instead of REQUEST_URI,
although it was strange that REQUEST_URI didn't work,
here is the solution in case anyone encounters with this problem.
notice that the dollar sign should not be inserted in the RewriteCond, because the extension will not be at the end of the THE_REQUEST variable.

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.(php|asp|aspx|html|htm)

RewriteRule .* example.com/err [R]